# Have I gone too far in factoring out repeated code in this example?

Tags: php

In a controller (PHP, CodeIgniter) I'm adding scripts & css to variables to be used in the view output. My initial coding looked like this:

```
private function _add_script($path, $where = self::ADD_LAST) {
    $html = "<script src='$path'></script>\n";
    switch($where) {
        case self::ADD_LAST:
            array_push($this->_data['script'], $html);
            break;
        case self::ADD_FIRST:
            array_unshift($this->_data['script'], $html);
            break;
    }
}

private function _add_css($path, self::ADD_LAST) {
    $html = "    <link rel='stylesheet' href='$path'>\n";
    switch($where) {
        case self::ADD_LAST:
            array_push($this->_data['css'], $html);
            break;
        case self::ADD_FIRST:
            array_unshift($this->_data['css'], $html);
            break;
    }
}
```

Well, I noticed that these two are basically just repeating themselves, so I immediately rewrote them into this format:

```
private function _add_script($path, $where = self::ADD_LAST) {
    $html = "<script src='$path'></script>\n";
    $this->_add_external('script', $html, $where);
}


private function _add_css($path, $where = self::ADD_LAST) {
    $html = "<link rel='stylesheet' href='$path'>\n";
    $this->_add_external('css', $html, $where);
}



private function _add_external($type, $html, $where) {
    switch($where) {
        case self::ADD_LAST:
            array_push($this->_data[$type], $html);
            break;
        case self::ADD_FIRST:
            array_unshift($this->_data[$type], $html);
            break;
    }
}
```

Does the second version seem like the way to go? Or perhaps a 3rd alternative. The requirements call for being able to add elements to the list either before or after all other elements already in the list.

Comment: Your rewrite would be good if you were adding many different tags. I.E. more than just the two (script and link)

Answer (score 4):

I think what you did was a good thing. I also think you could combine the first 2 functions as well.

Something like this:

```
private function _add_item($path, $type, $where = self::ADD_LAST) {
    $script = "<script src='$path'></script>\n";
    $css = "<link rel='stylesheet' href='$path'>\n";

    if ($type == 'script') {
        $html = $script; 
    }
    elseif ($type == 'css') {
        $html = $css;
    }

    $this->_add_external($type, $html, $where);
}
```

Or this:

```
private function _add_item($path, $type, $where = self::ADD_LAST) {
    $script = "<script src='$path'></script>\n";
    $css = "<link rel='stylesheet' href='$path'>\n";

    switch($type) {
        case 'script':
            $html = $script; 
            break;
        case 'type':
            $html = $css;
            break;
    }

    $this->_add_external($type, $html, $where);
}
```

Or this (My favorite):

```
private function _add_item($path, $type, $where = self::ADD_LAST) {
    $array['script'] = "<script src='$path'></script>\n";
    $array['css'] = "<link rel='stylesheet' href='$path'>\n";

    $html = $array[$type]; 

    $this->_add_external($type, $html, $where);
}
```

**EDIT:**

And I think this would work too, an all in one solution:

```
private function _add_item_external($path, $type, $where = self::ADD_LAST) {
    $array['script'] = "<script src='$path'></script>\n";
    $array['css'] = "<link rel='stylesheet' href='$path'>\n";

    switch($where) {
        case self::ADD_LAST:
            array_push($this->_data[$type], $array[$type]);
            break;
        case self::ADD_FIRST:
            array_unshift($this->_data[$type], $array[$type]);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can go "too far", can you? So long as what you do saves space and time, I say it is a good thing. It may make your code look sloppy, but just have two versions: one to look at and one for actually running?

Comment: @Mr_CryptoPrime That is just begging for insidious bugs to sneak through the discrepancies between the two versions of the code.